# ¿Por que node.replaceChild no funciona?

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas, tengo un `carousel` de `bootstrap` en el que, cuando hago `click` en las imágenes que sustituyen por un vídeo del servidor.

Este es el código de uno de los items:

```
<div class="item active" id="unboxing" onclick="PonerVideo(this)">
    <img src="img/unboxing.png">
</div>
```

Y cuando hago `click` llamo a esta función:

```
function PonerVideo(ele){
    var titulo = ele.id;
    var old = ele.firstChild;
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    var src = document.createElement("iframe");
    node.setAttribute("class", "embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9");
    src.setAttribute("class","embed-responsive-item");
    src.setAttribute("src","img/"+titulo+".mp4" );
    src.setAttribute("onclick", "Pausa(this)");
    node.appendChild(src);
    ele.replaceChild(node,old);
}
```

El vídeo sale bien, pero lo que hace es desplazar la foto debajo del vídeo, en vez de reemplazarla.

He probado a hacer `remove child` también, pero eso dejaba la foto en su sitio con el vídeo debajo.

Pongo un `iframe` porque si no el vídeo no cabe dentro del item del `carousel` y no se ve. Los vídeos son del servidor donde alojo la web, no son de youtube ni nada por el estilo.

Se me debe estar escapando algo pero no sé el que.

Comment: Hola Victor. ¿Puedes usar el snippet de codigo integrado en el editor de preguntas  (icono `<>`) para hacer un ejemplo donde se reproduzca el error? O tienes algun enlace online estilo jsfiddle? Recuerda mirar [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Aqui tienes una pequeña demo. Solo esta la primera imagen y si clickas en ella pasa lo que describia arriba: http://mural.uv.es/vicgalo/slide/portada.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `ele.firstChild` devuelve el `NodeText` que contiene el texto (*espacios*) que hay desde `onclick="PonerVideo(this)">` a `<img`.

### Solución 1:

Podrías usar [`ele.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild), en lugar de usar `ele.firstChild`:

> La propiedad de sólo lectura `ParentNode.firstElementChild` retorna el primer hijo del objeto del tipo `Element`, o bien `null` si no existen elementos hijos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function PonerVideo(ele){
    var titulo = ele.id;
    var old = ele.firstElementChild;
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    var src = document.createElement("iframe");
    node.setAttribute("class", "embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9");
    src.setAttribute("class","embed-responsive-item");
    src.setAttribute("src","img/"+titulo+".mp4" );
    src.setAttribute("onclick", "Pausa(this)");
    node.appendChild(src);
    ele.replaceChild(node,old);
}
```

```html
<div class="item active" id="unboxing" onclick="PonerVideo(this)">
    <img src="img/unboxing.png">
</div>
```

### Solución 2:

Modificar el `markup` y eliminar los espacios.

```
<div class="item active" id="unboxing" onclick="PonerVideo(this)"><img src="img/unboxing.png"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Estas cosas son las qu eme hacen sentir super tonto una vez resueltas -.-